# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodules'

Tags: python-3.x, module, package

I'm new in Python and I'm facing module problems.

When I run my code using the run button in PyCharm ide, the code works fine. It shows the following call in prompt:

D:\Desenvolvimento\Python\HeadFirstPython\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Desenvolvimento/Python/HeadFirstPython/webapp/vsearch4web.py

- Serving Flask app "vsearch4web" (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
  ....

but when I use the terminal and run as follow:

D:\Desenvolvimento\Python\HeadFirstPython\webapp>**python vsearch4web.py**

I get the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "vsearch4web.py", line 2, in 
from mymodules.vsearch import search4letters
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodules'

PS: If I change the vsearchforweb.py to root it also works, but I want to use inside the webapp direcoty.

My imports:

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from mymodules.vsearch import search4letters

and my structure:

HeadFirstPython\webapp\vsearch4web.py (where the imports are)
HeadFirstPython\mymodules\vsearch.py (when I did the exercise to create a module)

If I use >conda list I have the following results:

sqlite                    3.33.0               h2a8f88b_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_3
vsearch                   1.0                      pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0
wheel                     0.35.1                     py_0

Could anyone help me?

Comment: please post the relevant code (particularly the import lines) as well as the structure of your project.

Comment: Added more information to the post.